# Scrapy: one jobdir per spider

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have a `Scrapy` project with multiple spiders. How can I run all spiders with its own `jobdir`? I show in the following code how am I executing all spiders with a single `jobdir`.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

settings = get_project_settings()
settings.set('JOBDIR', 'saved_crawl', priority='cmdline')


process = CrawlerProcess(settings)

process.crawl('spider1')
process.crawl('spider2')
process.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found that the solution is very simple. I just need to define `JOBDIR` in the custom settings dict, for each spider:

```
class Spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    custom_settings = {'JOBDIR': 'crawl_spider1'}
```